Form Input Missing in FastAPI, Displays JSON Instead During Testing
I am trying out the examples from FastAPI: FastAPI > Learn > Tutorial-User Guide > Form Models
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, Form
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class FormData(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str


@app.post("/login/")
async def login(data: Annotated[FormData, Form()]):
    return data

When I test it by accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, the form doesn't appear; instead, it shows a JSON example. 
If I input data using JSON format, I get the following error: 422 Unprocessable Entity.
What steps am I doing wrong?

Which version of FastAPI are you using? Pydantic models as forms was added in a very recent release (just four days ago), namely 0.113.0. If you're using an older version, this won't work as you expect it to.

pip show fastapi
Name: fastapi
Version: 0.112.2

Thanks for your comment. It seems I'd better to upgrade fastapi to the newest version

As @MatsLindh said, when I upgrade to a newer version, the form will be shown correctly.
(.venv) PS C:\test\LxFastApi\pythonProject> pip show fastapi     
Name: fastapi
Version: 0.114.0
Summary: FastAPI framework, high performance, easy to learn, fast to code, ready for production
Home-page: https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi
Author:
Author-email: =?utf-8?q?Sebasti=C3=A1n_Ram=C3=ADrez?= <tiangolo@gmail.com>
License:
Location: C:\test\LxFastApi\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages
Requires: pydantic, starlette, typing-extensions
Required-by:




